Election result might be broken
Recently an election happened on a network site https://islam.stackexchange.com/election it ended on 13 November but the result is still incomplete.
Is that a bug?
Do results now take longer to process?
Did something go wrong?

Judging from the fact that no new builds were deployed over November 14 and 15, those were presumably holidays or the company was occupied with other things (such as a meetup).

While the elections is partly automated, when it's finished, the diamond is not assigned automatically. It needs a staff member (Community Manager usually) to go over the results, verify them, contact the winner, etc. This can indeed take few days.

The election has been resolved. See the results here. A very unexciting delay was caused by me being out due to illness last week and forgetting to ask someone to conclude it.

Just out of curiosity, was the lack of builds over those days also related to you being out or was it just coincidence? Curious as to whether it was related or just a red herring.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I am not sure what you are referring to in terms of builds. But as far as I am aware, my absence last week didn't cause hangups with anything else.

The election ended on November 13, and on Friday, November 15 the last build pushed out to the sites was dated November 13. Typically, from what I've seen, a new build is pushed out to the network every business day except in cases like when there's a company meetup. Prior to your post here, due to the lack of builds last Thursday and Friday I'd assumed that the lack of the election announcement was because the whole company was off. I guess that was just a red herring, though.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I'd generally advise against attempting to paint a narrative based on, of all things, build numbers and their dates. No meaningful conclusions can be made about such things except that there were no builds released after Wednesday.

@Spevacus well, if Spencer was a developer this could make some sense to ask, but as CM, he's not responsible for any builds. I think Sonic was under the impression SE might have been in "code freeze", which was a thing in the past. (Anyway, I do agree that even in the best case, it's just some very far fetched guess.) (Edit: found some reference for code freeze)
